# Why are visual and ILS approach angles for a Cessna 172 often different?

Tags: approach, ils, visual-approaches, glideslope

> **NOTE**: I fly in Canada. Also, the question is based on my experience on light aircraft like a C172.

It is known that the (standard) glideslope flown in an ILS approach is 3°. However, that doesn't seem to be the case for a visual approach. Some basic high school math tells us that an aircraft 1 NM away from the aiming point on a 3° ILS glidepath would be at 319 FT AGL, whereas I'm taught to be at around 600 FT AGL (or, "ideally" 500' AGL- the same as when turning crosswind) when turning on (approximately) a 1 NM final from base in a VFR traffic pattern- making my approach path <sup>[2]</sup> about 4.7° - 5.6°.

**What is the reason for this difference in glideslope between a visual and ILS approach?**

An answer at [this PPRuNe post](https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/10272-why-3-degrees-ils.html) says that the angle was chosen as it supposedly worked well for the flight computer to be able to AUTO LAND the aircraft. However, that begs the question: **why enforce this even in a CAT 1 ILS approach where the pilot takes manual control (once visual) way before touchdown?**

Comment: Why do you think you should fly such a steep final in a VFR pattern?  I was trained to roll out on final exactly on the VGSI, where one exists.

Comment: "whereas I'm supposed to be at around 600 FT AGL when turning on (approximately) a 1 NM final from base in a VFR traffic pattern- making my "glideslope"[2] about 5.6o." According to whom? Please provide a reference.

Comment: @Pilothead According to all the instructors at my school. The airport elevation is (rounded off to) 200’, so we’re asked to be at (about) 800’ at the beginning of final. I will cross check tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: @Pilothead I Cross-checked with my instructor who says the ideal height at 1NM final is 500' AGL, and another student whose instructor says approx. 600' AGL. Added an answer based on the conversations.

Comment: Are you sure you want to always put yourself in a situation where you are 100% reliant on the engine to make the runway during VFR flying in a light airplane?  I was taught to have the power at idle during VFR final approaches in single-engine light aircraft.  This results in a glide path steeper than the ILS glide slope.

Comment: @quietflyer And as I alluded to earlier, that works fine if your plan is to fly primarily light, low-inertia, high-lift airplanes like a 152 or 172.  Energy management in an airplane only 500 or 1,000 pounds heavier and 5 or 10 kts faster is like a whole different world.

Comment: @quietflyer Yes, I have heard that being recommended as well. Although it's customary to not do so on a "normal" approach, I think no one's gonna mind it if I do (especially because it's recommended and GOOD practice). I recently gave my PPL Flight test and my examiner also recommended keeping the flaps to 20 until closer to the RWY and just let the plane "GLIDE" at 1500 RPM, so we don't have to make too many power changes.

Answer (score 2):

Several factors and thoughts here.

1. I think you might be flying a very light aircraft with very slow approach speeds that support steeper approaches, also meaning less vertical descent energy to be absorbed in the round out/flare.  As you move to heavier/faster aircraft you’re going to need to be staying fairly close to 3 degrees.  In my aircraft a descent steeper than 3-4 degrees is going to *absolutely* require one of two things.  I’m either going to be flying the final *well* below 1.3x V(s) *or* I am going to float a long ways and need a very long runway, like literally 1,000 more feet.
2. Remember that VASI/VGSI systems are most usually also 3 degrees.  Turning in from one NM at 600 feet is putting you well above the VASI visual slope.  Again, that may be fine for a slower/lighter aircraft but if you’re flying something like a 182 or Bonanza, it’s really, really hard to get that plane on the ground unless you are very deliberate about matching the right speed to the right descent angle.
3. I very much disagree with your quote PPRuNe quote about auto land.  The 3 degree convention for ILS *distantly* predates any modern auto-landing systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yes, you're right- I fly a Cessna 172. I have been trained to not look at the PAPI lights but try to achieve the "right picture of the RWY" while judging height on approach. Apart from that, I take it from your answer that the 3 degree angle was decided to make the NAVAID universally usable by all aircraft types (since both a C172 and a B747 can approach t a 3 degree glideslope), right? I haven't done any instrument approaches in the C172 yet, so I don't have a lot of understanding at this point.

Comment: @PapaMike99 Remember that landing is the ultimate energy management maneuver.  I have to bring my vertical energy to zero at touchdown and my horizontal energy to zero before the end of the runway.  A light aircraft at 60Kt GS is descending at 600 FPM in order to go from 600 AGL to 0 AGL.  600FPM x 1900 Lbs (vert) and 60Kts x 1900 Lbs (horz) is well within the control authority available in a 172 on 2,000 feet of runway.  600FPM x 600,000 Lbs (v) and 150Kt x 600,000 Lbs (h) is a profoundly different problem to solve, the technical term for these kinds of energy is “an ass-ton,” LOL.

Comment: @PapaMike99 a loaded 747 would need a flare longer than the entire runway to fully arrest a 6 degree descent at 150-ish Kts.  At some point, aeronautical engineers, landing gear structural engineers, runway strength civil engineers, land planners who had to buy runway land, found 3 degrees to be about the right compromise of safe approach speeds, reasonable flap and elevator sizes, reasonable brake design, reasonable land use, etc.

Comment: makes sense for an airliner. But don’t Cessna’s also approach at 3 degrees on ILS? If so then why? 3 degrees would put a 172 much lower than what we’re taught here in BC, Canada!

Comment: @PapaMike99 it would be impractical to have a ground-based ILS system configurable to specific aircraft, and creates the possibility of *the airport* being mis-configured for the landing, not the airplane.  We already have non-precisions approaches using WAAS GPS that would allow you to determine your own vertical profile at or above the minimum altitudes.  But by not relying on a ground-based ILS, you become subject to higher minimums.  So if you wanted to fly in steeper than the ILS, you’d request the GPS approach and manage your own altitude, within the limits of the published approach.